# Django server in a Docker

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose

I'm starting to develop an application with a Django back-end, and I wish to do it inside a Docker. I almost managed to do it, but I'm still having an issue. Currently I have two containers running :

[image: docker ps]

The first one contains my django app and the complete command is

```
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

and the second one is hosting my database.

My docker-compose.yml file is this one :

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD : root
      MYSQL_DATABASE : ml_gui
  back:
    build: ./back/
    command: python3 manage.py runserver
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and my django settings concerning the database is :

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'ml_gui',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'",
        },
        'TEST': {
            'CHARSET': 'utf8',
            'COLLATION': 'utf8_general_ci',
        },
    },
}
```

The problem is, when I do requests outside of the container (I've tried in my browser, with curl and with Postman) on localhost:8000, I have no answer. But, when I do the same request inside the container with curl, it works.

How could I make those requests work from outside of the containers ?

Comment: Do you have any firewall on the host machine? like iptables

Comment: Yes, I didn't know I had iptables installed.

Comment: Did the port 8000 got exposed in iptables? Docker should do it automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should never run `./manage.py runserver` in production, it is only for testing... also if you dont specify the IP address that the server listens to it is available only for localhost (see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#runserver))

so in you docker-compose.yml the command should be

```
./manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution works. Because I had iptables I tried to remove it, then uninstalled docker. I reinstalled docker-ce following the instructions on the website and not by doing apt install docker.